# Compare files from different folders

Tags: unix, printing, compare, sdiff

I would like to write a script that compares files from different folders; compare is done between different folder with the same filename.
Eg

> Folder A: filename1, filename2, filename3
> Folder B: filename1, filename2, filename3

desired Output, written to an output file:

> filename1:
> different1
> different2
>
> filename2
> differentA
> differentB

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use?

```
diff -ur path1 path2
```